# Ajax doesn't working with .htaccess rewrite

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, .htaccess, fullcalendar

I have a script for a calendar, but it seems that when I want to send data through ajax I get `parsererror` because I changed the URL through htaccess. I put the code in a test project without changing the URL and it works, how could I modify the code so that it accepts more parameters for the "filme" page.
I noticed that does not enter in "success" but the data is added to the database

## .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-z0-9-]+)(\/)?(?(2)([0-9]+))$ index.php?pag=$1&id=$3 [NC,L]

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

## index.php

```
<?php

    if(isset($_GET['pag']))
        switch($_GET['pag']){
            case ($_GET['pag'] == 'index'):
                include('pages/acasa.php');
                break;

            case 'filme':
                include('pages/filme.php');
                break;

            default:
                include('pages/eroare.php');
                break;
        }
    else
        include('pages/acasa.php');

?>
```

## ajax

```
function doSubmit() {
    $("#createEventModal").modal('hide');
    var title = $('#title').val();
    var startTime = $('#startTime').val();
    var endTime = $('#endTime').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'pages/filme.php',
        data: 'action=add&title=' + title + '&start=' + startTime + '&end=' + endTime,
        type: "POST",
        success: function(json) {
            $("#calendar").fullCalendar('renderEvent', {
                    id: json.id,
                    title: title,
                    start: startTime,
                    end: endTime,
                },
                true);
        }
    });

}
```

## php code

```
if($_POST['action'] == "add")
    {
        mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO `filme` (
                    `title` ,
                    `start` ,
                    `end`
                    )
                    VALUES (
                    '".mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["title"])."',
                    '".mysqli_real_escape_string($con, date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($_POST["start"])))."',
                    '".mysqli_real_escape_string($con, date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($_POST["end"])))."'
                    )");
        header('Content-Type: application/json');

         echo '{"id":"'.mysqli_insert_id($con).'"}';
        exit;
    }
```

## Full code

```
filme.php : https://pastebin.com/B8Cu4rRX
script.js : https://pastebin.com/gtR3SwSP
```

Comment: As an aside, really, please create an object in PHP and then use json_encode() to generate JSON, it will be much less prone to errors.

Comment: P.S. If all the data is being added to the DB successfully, it suggests to me that sending the parameters is not an issue? But if it isn't entering the "success" then the issue maybe more with the response. Have you looked in your browser's Network tools to see what the outcome of the request is? Or the Console for script errors? And/or the PHP error logs (assuming you've got logging switched on)?